# How can I fetch the BuyerID based on buyer-email using Amazon MWS Api

Tags: amazon-mws

When parsing through Orders from Amazon MWS Api report type `_GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_`,

I can see the Buyer Name property and other information about the buyer (address, etc.).

However, I don't see a BuyerID. I know I can use buyer-email (ie: fooamazoncustomer@marketplace.amazon.com) as a unique customer identifier.

But my purpose is to link the orders made of such buyer to his [public page](http://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/AURL5YGBXZVKQ) which I need the `BuyerID` instead of buyer-email.

So my question is, how can I fetch the BuyerID based on buyer-email using Amazon MWS Api or scraping?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.  Amazon uses anonymized emails to protect the customer and therefor they're probably not going to give you an id where you can see their profile or public page.  I did verify that you can only get the buyers email address, again it's anonymous, from the Orders API using the GetOrder operation.

Comment: @ScottG Thanks for confirming sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks ScottG and Sagar.

**Answer:**
I don't believe it's possible. Amazon uses anonymized emails to protect the customer and therefor they're probably not going to give you an id where you can see their profile or public page. I did verify that you can only get the buyers email address, again it's anonymous, from the Orders API using the GetOrder operation. – ScottG

Comment: Is the email provided always the same for the same buyer?